# Logstash should log only grok parsed messages

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, grok

Currently I have a ELK stack in which logs are shipped by filebeat and after some filters in logstash, it is forwarded to ES. As there are a lot of servers and logs, a huge logs are coming to logstash, but I have configured the filter to only process a very specific type of log message. Which it is doing fine, but the logs which are not even matching are logged in logstash.log file. As I mentioned earlier that huge logs are coming, the size of logstash.log file is soon reaching to a high value and there is space issue coming up. How to configure the logstash so that I only log the processed logs, and not all.

Answer (score 0):

You could use logrotate to automatically rotate on either a daily basis or once it hits a certain threshold.  You could then set the number of rotations to be 1 or 2.  This would allow you time to see what is going to the file in case you need to troubleshoot, but purge before it creates space contention.